# “It might be her brother” vs “He might be her brother”

Tags: word-choice, personal-pronouns

Why do we use *it might be her brother* instead of *he*? For example,

> Who is that guy with Susan? I'm not sure it might be her brother.

Why do we use the third person singular *it* instead of *he* might be her brother?

Comment: Do we...........?

Comment: You can use _he_ here, but the impersonal and largely dummy 'it' is normally used. Who's that? It's us. Who dropped this? It was me. // 'It's her brother' may be formed from the cleft 'It is her brother who is with her'.

Answer (score 1):

I don't entirely agree with the other replies.  For example

"Who is that?"

"It's John."

---

"Who's there?"

"It's me."

We don't usually say "He's John" or "I am me" in those circumstances. Similarly I would be unsurprised to hear.

"Who is that guy with Susan?"

"I'm not sure it might be her brother.

---

My answer is that we are using the same impersonal 'it' that applies when we say. "It is raining."

As for why, well it's just one of those quirks of language. Some unknown but influential person said it that way once and others followed suit.

Comment: So no grammatical rule I'm missing here?

Comment: I suspect it's a hangover from the Norman Conquest of England and therefore from French.  I'm thinking of deleting my answer because, on reflection,  it isn't really an answer. I hope someone else comes up with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly acceptable to use "he" in this case rather than "it". Many people would consider it preferable. presuming that the gender of the person is known to be male. You are going to use "it" when the gender of the person is indeterminate.

> Who is that person with Susan?
>
> I don't know, it might be her brother.
>
> No, it's her sister.

Comment: This is not correct. _It is her brother_ and _He is her brother_ are both grammatical, and in this context interchangeable. The _he_ statement is about the identity of the unknown person; the _it_ is a "presentational" statement about the situation. Where the question is about the unknown person (_Who is that person with Susan?_) either makes sense, but when the question is a different one (eg _Why is Susan so happy?_) only the _It_ form is coherent.